# Kendo: Passing Parent Model to Ajax Data Source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a simple Grid in a MVC4 [ChildAction].

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
   .Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.UserLoginID);
    columns.Bound(p => p.UserName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.UserStatus);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("SearchUserResult_Read", "Search"))
)
)
```

How do I pass the Parent's Model (Search Query Criteria) in the .Ajax() call above?

Note that I do pass the Parent's Model to the Action via this code so have it in the Controller's ChildAction, just not in the Ajax call:

```
@Html.Action("SearchUserResultGrid", "Search",
       new {SearchQueryCriteriaViewModel = Model})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

Simply pass the model to the view:

```
View(model)
```

Then in the Razor view

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
```

Comment: How does this answer your initial question?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("SearchUserResult_Read", "Search", new { SearchQueryCriteriaViewModel = Model}))
```